# "Even a crab" - Japanese proverbs (?)

Tags: expressions

Coming across these kind of constructs:

カニでもわかる＋名詞句

カニでもできる...

カニでも使える...

etc.

What does it mean? How is it used?

In general, what main associations would a "crab" create from a Japanese cultural perspective? E.g. lion - brave; tanuki - sly; crab - ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally didn't know the very exact expression, but I can make a reasonable guess that it's a variant of サルでも…… ("Even monkeys do..."). The implication is quite similar to "for dummies" in English, which is to state its easiness in exaggerated manner.

[One of web pages](http://jovivi.seesaa.net/article/18412361.html) using the phrase declares:

> 昔、サルでもわかるナントカってのがありましたが、その上をいきます。**カニでも分かる**簿記！ホ乳類じゃなくても大丈夫！
>
> *There were some (books?) like "~~ For Monkeys" quite some time ago, but we'll go much farther. Bookkeeping **For Crabs**! You don't even need to be a mammal!*

By the way I'd like to add that my favorite one is [ヤドンでもできるポケモン乱数調整](http://blog.livedoor.jp/rurou_raori/) ("Pokémon RNG Manipulation for Slowpokes").

Comment: I think かに came from さるかに合戦.

Comment: Good too know about the Slowpoke, too. Always wondered what that critter was called in Japanese!

Comment: @user9771 [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Japanese_Pok%C3%A9mon_names) you are :)